How to use mongod 7 in loopback 3 application without migrating to loopback 4?
I’m currently working with a LoopBack 3 application, and i am experiencing license issues with our MongoDB version 4. Upon researching, I found that MongoDB versions 6 and 7 are not supported in LoopBack 3.(https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/MongoDB-connector.html)
Unsupported OP_QUERY command: listCollections. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal This is the error i got when i try to run my app with mongo 7
Given that migrating to LoopBack 4 would be challenging due to time constraints, I’m exploring alternative solutions. Here are a couple of options I’m considering:
Mounting LoopBack 3 on LoopBack 4: This approach involves integrating LoopBack 3 with LoopBack 4 and developing new features in LoopBack 4. However, this also necessitates dealing with the MongoDB version change.
Using Mongoose within LoopBack 3: I’ve thought about incorporating Mongoose (version 7) for handling MongoDB connections and model operations. However, I’m unsure about the feasibility and potential challenges of this approach.
I’d greatly appreciate any advice or guidance from those who have encountered similar issues. Specifically, I’m looking for insights on:

The practicality and potential pitfalls of mounting LoopBack 3 on    LoopBack 4.
The feasibility of using Mongoose within a LoopBack 3 application, and any integration tips or best practices.

Thank you in advance for your help!

"Upon researching, I found that MongoDB versions 6 and 7 are not supported in LoopBack 3." could you evidence the statement? I couldn't find any related docs

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/MongoDB-connector.html @AlexBlex
PLease check this link as well

It helps. So, there are many moving parts: LoopBack uses mongodb-connector https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-connector-mongodb, which uses mongodb-native-driver https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native which implements the wire protocol. The error comes from there, not loopback itself.

Thanks for the clarification. I see that the compatibility issue stems from the mongodb-native-driver used by the loopback-connector-mongodb.@AlexBlex

correct, the driver compatibility with mongodb https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/v3.6/compatibility/  v7 requires a driver 4.0+

the 5x connector requires the driver ^3.2.4 https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-connector-mongodb/blob/5.x/package.json#L45 , which means "less than 4". They bumped the driver version to 4.x only in v7-alpha connector https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/672

you will need to backport the PR to 5.x branch of the connector as it's the latest version compatible with loopback 3, or downgrade mongodb to v6.

i am currently using    loopback-connector-mongodb: 5.4.0 @AlexBlex

5.4.0 is still 5.x branch. It uses ^3.2.4  driver https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-connector-mongodb/blob/v5.4.0/package.json#L42, so all my comments above still stand - either backport the PR from v7 to v5.4.0 or downgrade to mongo v6 - it still works with native drivers v3.x
